# Nonnegative solution to underdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I would like to show that the underdetermined system $Ax=b,\; x\ge 0$, with $b$ being a positive vector and $A$ being a binary matrix, has at least one solution.

I've seen several other related posts, but I think that the sitatuion here is somehow different. Your helpful comments are much appreciated!

Comment: To be clear, by "positive vector," you mean that every component of the vector is positive?

Answer (score 0):

All we need to do here is to perform some [Gaussian elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) on the [augmented matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix). The idea is that by transforming this matrix into reduced row echelon form, you can find all possible solutions to your system of equations.

At the end, you can tell if there a solution exists by checking that you don't have a row of all $0$s except with a nonzero last element in the reduced row echelon form of the augmented matrix.

Note that this process works even when we don't have the restrictions that $b$ is a positive vector and $A$ is a binary matrix.

A final note: There are cases where even an underdetermined system doesn't have any solution. For example, consider the case $A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{matrix}\right]$ and $b=\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\end{matrix}\right]$.

Comment: Thanks Peter. You are right and we can find solutions (or say if there is any such solution) using this procedure. What I want to show indeed is the existence of a solution for a generic binary $A$ and generic strictly positive $b$. I was looking forward to using a Farkas lemma type result if it is possible.

Comment: @mst82 I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Farkas Lemma. Perhaps you could update your question to ask for this type of result (and I can get rid of this answer), or you could ask a new question?

Comment: Using Farkas lemma is not necessarily helpful. The question I got now is this: When $Ax=b$ is underdetermined, how does the Gaussian elimination work (since we have fewer rows than columns)? Is it the same way as when the system is not underdetermined?

Comment: @mst82 yes, it's just the same. Wikipedia has [a good example here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form). The key point is that if there is no solution then we will still get a row of all $0$s except for the last column entry.